# Question about 'const' functions, c++

Tags: c++, constants, member-functions, function-qualifier

I understand that when I declare a member function as const I actually say that I will not change the class. My question - does 'class' refer to (*)this instance or to the class in general?

For exmaple - if I have a const member function that create a new instance of the same class and edit this instance, is that legal?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` refers to the instance on which you call the function, which is also why static member functions cannot be declared const. A const function can read, but not write, the fields of the `this` instance, and it can only call static and const methods of `this`, but it has full access to the global scope.